# jQuery slide to the bottom of page

Tags: jquery

Is there a way, using jQuery, I can slide to the bottom of the page I am currently on? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may checkout the [following article](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/10/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-bottom-or-top.html):

```
$('#scrlBotm').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 1500);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you may use this code.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("body").height()}, 800);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

If you wanted it on click:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
});
```

See [**demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/PUgpz/) and [**demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/PUgpz/)